# RecyclerView / Firebase- Trying to retrieve a document with an certain id that i get from an another collection

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I'm a beginner in Java / Android code.

I"m using Firebase Cloud Database.
I'm trying to do a "favorite list" in a RecyclerView for each users. To do that, I'm trying to retrieve data from a certain collection. To retrieve the data, I use a certain id that i find in my users sub-collection "Favorites" where you can find document with the "id" field.
When I have the "id" from the "sub-collection" I want to see if any document in another collection ("etablissements") this time, have the same id. And if the "id" field match, I try to retrieve data from this specific document and "inject" it in the RecyclerView.

I'm struggling with the Adapter (FavoriteAdapter).

```
public class FavoriteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FavoriteAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private final Context context;
private final List<FavoriteItem> items = Lists.newArrayList();

private String idInFav;
String name;


public FavoriteAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;

    String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid();

    NewApplication.firestore().collection("users").document(uid).collection("favorites").addSnapshotListener((snapshots, e) -> {
        if (e != null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
            return;
        }
        for (DocumentChange dc : snapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
            switch (dc.getType()) {

                case ADDED:

                    idInFav = dc.getDocument().getString("id");

                    NewApplication.firestore().collection("etablissements").whereEqualTo("id", idInFav).addSnapshotListener((snapshots1, e1) -> {
                        if (e1 != null) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e1);
                            return;
                        }

                        for (DocumentSnapshot ds : snapshots1) {
                            items.add(dc.getNewIndex(), ds.toObject(FavoriteItem.class));
                        }
                    });

                    break;

                case MODIFIED:

                    idInFav = dc.getDocument().getString("id");
                    NewApplication.firestore().collection("etablissements").whereEqualTo("id", idInFav).addSnapshotListener((snapshots1, e1) -> {
                        if (e1 != null) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e1);
                            return;
                        }

                        for (DocumentSnapshot ds : snapshots1) {
                            name = ds.getString("nom");

                            items.set(dc.getNewIndex(), ds.toObject(FavoriteItem.class));
                        }
                    });

                    break;

                case REMOVED:

                    items.remove(dc.getOldIndex());
                    break;
            }
            FavoriteAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fav_item, viewGroup, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

    FavoriteItem user = items.get(i);

    SimpleDateFormat mdformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd / MM / yyyy");
    String date = mdformat.format(user.timestamp);

    viewHolder.textViewHeadInFav.setText(user.nom);
    viewHolder.textViewDescInFav.setText(user.description);
     viewHolder.dateSinceWhenFav.setText(date);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    @BindView(R.id.textViewHeadInFav)
    protected TextView textViewHeadInFav;
    @BindView(R.id.textViewDescInFav)
    protected TextView textViewDescInFav;
    @BindView(R.id.imageViewInFav)
    protected ImageView imageViewInFav;
    @BindView(R.id.dateSinceWhenFav)
    protected TextView dateSinceWhenFav;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }
}
```

}

In items arraylist, I manage to get the data I want from the right collection (etablissements) and the right document but there's two problems. First of all, it's looks like my

```
NewApplication.firestore().collection("users").document(uid).collection("favorites")
```

is called too late. It's called after everything.
And the second problem is : I can't get the "items" (arraylist) with "new" data I just add / set on it, after the second "NewApplication......" items is equal to [].

And because my items (arraylist) is empty, getItemCount return 0 and then my onBindViewHolder is not even called.

Is there any way to fix it ? If yes, please help me, I'm struggling with it for like +10Hours.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's because you have a callback inside a callback. You need to call notifyItemInserted after                             items.add(dc.getNewIndex(), ds.toObject(FavoriteItem.class));
You need to notifyItemChanged after items.set(dc.getNewIndex(), ds.toObject(FavoriteItem.class));
 These are not synchronous and are called after your notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: @Debanjan So I have to change it like this : in Case Added :
for (DocumentSnapshot ds : snapshots1) {
                                items.add(dc.getNewIndex(), ds.toObject(FavoriteItem.class));
                                FavoriteAdapter.this.notifyItemInserted(dc.getNewIndex());
                            }
and same thing with case modified, i mean i just changed insert by changed right ?

Comment: Yes, And you need to be accurate with the index.

Comment: @Debanjan Weird, my second callback is still called too late. It's still called after everything. by second callback i mean "NewApplication.firestore().collection("etablissements").whereEqualTo("id", idInFav)"

Comment: There's nothing "late" in an asynchronous request, it can run anytime, you cannot estimate the time. refactor your code based on callbacks

Comment: Don't get confused. Just remember when you are attaching a listener, it can be called anytime in the future, your second callback is late because may be it's doing heavy processing.

Comment: @Debanjan Alright. But how can I "force" my first callback to "wait" for the second callback to finish what he's doing ?

Comment: You can't. Or Only if you can call your first callback from inside your second callback

Comment: @Debanjan Ohhh I see now. So for my problem, I can't do anything.